# Create scrollbars one an ext js dataview

Tags: javascript, extjs, scrollbar, dataview

On the project I am working on I have a dataview inside a panel which is constrained in size. I am having trouble figuring out how I can put scrollbars on the view to make sure that all the items in the dataview can all be displayed if they overflow the size of the dataview/panel. My code is very similar to that on http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/examples/view/data-view/viewer.html.

If you edit this code and change the width of the dataview to something smaller e.g. 310 you will see that the images overflow the panel and are hidden. How can I put a scrollbar on this so that I can scroll to the hidden items? I have tried 'autoscroll: true' to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your casing is wrong for `autoScroll`.  Capitalize the `S` and it should work:

```
Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
    store: store,
    autoScroll: true,
    ///...
})
```